# How to check visibility of a Flutter widget even when covered by another

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to find a way to check the visibility of a Flutter widget when it's either off screen or when it's obscured by another, for example Drawer, Dialog or BottomSheet.

[visibility_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector) helps with checking whether it's on the screen or not but does not work with the second use case (known limitation).

Is there a lower lever api that I can use to check whether a widget is actually visible to the user?

My use case: I'm adding a widget to the Overlay when something external happens (similar to Tooltip but not on long press). If the user opens for example the Drawer, the widget will appear  on top. I want to detect that the child is not visible and delay or cancel the action.

Answer (score 1):

#### Do I understand your problem?

- You have a widget you want to always be on top?
- You want the user to interact with that widget first before doing other things?

#### **Use design patterns to make coding easier, your users will thank you.**

You can show a [Dialog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75CsnyRXf5I) on-top of other widgets with the `showGeneralDialog` or `showDialog` functions. Because Dialogs are a design-pattern used in many apps, users will already know how to use them.

#### **Define app behavior with explicit state.**

**It is too hard to derive app behavior from rendered UI, not all devices are the same size and shape.** This means you should try to write a variable that describes your situation and then write the code you need to make that variable's value correct. It sounds like you want a variable like `bool overlayIsShowing`.

Comment: No, I'm trying to do something like a [Popover](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/)

Comment: Understood. The Flutter word for that concept is a [Tooltip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeEfD5fI-5Q). Tooltips are supported and built-in because they are part of Material Design. Any time your UI is different from Material Design, expect a challenge.

Comment: I did find a package that seems similar to what you need.  https://pub.dev/packages/simple_tooltip

Comment: The Flutter Tooltip is only for displaying a label on long press or mouse hover.
The simple_tooltip widget is not quite what I'm looking for style wise, and the original problem I posted above still applies.